# Как убрать растягивание в RecyclerView при прокрутке?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Искал решение проблемы, но у всех увеличивается промежутки. А меня интересует как убрать растягивание текста.
[image: кароткое, потому что нельзя больше размер использовать]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".ui.create_channel.CreateChannelFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/message_rec"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:translationX="0dp"
    android:translationY="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="80dp"
    android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#AAA">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vlog_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="11dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vlog_body"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#9C9C9C"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Хочу, чтобы текст при прокрутке не растягивался, но он растягивается.

Comment: Попробуйте у recycler view высоту сделать wrap_content

Comment: @soundsofnature попробовал и у recyclerview и у материнского контейнера и вместе - к сожалению, ничего из этого не работает

Comment: android:overScrollMode="never"

Comment: @pie большое спасибо! Это сработало.